# MySQL insert multiple tuples from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which is *emp* table and *dept* table.

Below is a sample of emp table.

```
empno, firstname, lastname, workdept, salary
000010, Christine, Haas, A00, 312750.00
000020, Michael, Thompson, B01, 161250.00
```

And this is a sample of dept table.

```
deptno, deptname, mgrno, admrdept
A00, Spiffy Computer Service DIV., 000010, A00
B01, Planning, 000020, A00
```

I want to insert the information from this two tables into a new table called *dept2* with the following columns :.

```
did, dname, budget, managerid
```

- did = deptno
- dname = deptname
- Budget =  the budget of each department as
  20% more than the total salary of all employees in the department
- managerid = mgrno

I have no problem inserting did,dname and managerid into the table. The only problem I am facing is the budget column as I am required not to use the JOIN statement or even triggers for this query. I'm still a beginner at MySQL so go easy on me .

Comment: Why can't you use a JOIN? Which server are you actually using? (mysql and sql-server are two competing products, that are similar but different)

Comment: @TZHX I'm still new to MySQL, even though I have done my fair research on the internet on it, I am not far in the course I am in to have learn JOIN statement yet. Sorry for the confusing tag, I be editing sql-server tag out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sub-query,

`INSERT INTO Dept2
SELECT D.Deptno,D.Deptname, (SELECT SUM(salary)*1.20 FROM Emp WHERE       workdept=D.deptno),D.mgrno
FROM Dept D`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that does your job

```
INSERT INTO dept2
SELECT D.deptno,D.deptname,E.salary+((E.salary*20)/100),D.mgrno
FROM emptable E
JOIN depttable D ON E.workdept=D.deptno
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/293463)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but is there any way that the query can be done without JOIN?

Comment: No u cannot do without join unless and otherwise you include `salary` column in `depttable`. If u do so,it will break normalization concepts @Kaze Toushin

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried but I think

```
INSERT INTO Dept2 (did, dname, budget, managerid)
SELECT D.Deptno,D.Deptname, SUM(E.salary)*1.20,D.mgrno  
FROM Dept D, Emp E
WHERE E.workdept=D.deptno
Group by d.deptno, d.deptname,d.mgrno
```

should work